# SDL_PeepEvents won't handle window close

Tags: c++, sdl

I am calling `SDL_PeepEvents( sdlevent, EVENT_BUFFER_SIZE, SDL_GETEVENT, SDL_FIRSTEVENT, SDL_SYSWMEVENT );` however after a few seconds of runtime and mucking around with the window (resizing/moving/minimizing) it won't pick up an event when the x is clicked to close window.

```
void Window::pollWindowEvents(  )
{
    const int EVENT_BUFFER_SIZE = 16;
    SDL_Event sdlevent[ EVENT_BUFFER_SIZE ];    //The SDL event that we will poll to get events.

    SDL_PumpEvents(  );
    int numEvents = SDL_PeepEvents( sdlevent, EVENT_BUFFER_SIZE, SDL_GETEVENT, SDL_FIRSTEVENT, SDL_SYSWMEVENT );

    std::cout << numEvents << std::endl;

    for ( int i = 0; i < numEvents; ++i )
    {
        switch ( sdlevent[ i ].type )
        {
        case SDL_QUIT:
            closed = true;
            std::cout << sdlevent[ i ].type << std::endl;
            break;
        default:
            std::cout << sdlevent[ i ].type << std::endl;
            break;
        };
    }
}
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You are processing only up to 16 events every frame. There is a lot of events left in the queue and it will take some time to process them at that speed. Why aren't you using `SDL_PollEvent`?

Comment: I was not using `SDL_PollEvent` because I wanted to handle the keyboard events separately. I've been meaning to post the solution for a few days but it seems as though the event queue was getting filled up with  the events I was not actually handling. Once I started handling them I found it worked fine. The way I have ended up handling them would however allow me to use `SDL_PollEvent` which now that it has been mentioned I may just do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When calling `SDL_PeepEvents()` I was only processing a select range of events in the queue with the remaining events being unprocessed. This resulted in the event queue becoming saturated with these unprocessed events and as a result stopped the events I wanted to process from being processed. This was easily resolved by processing ALL events in the event queue.